# Equation of a plane passing through a line and a separate point.

Tags: analytic-geometry

Is it possible to find the equation of a plane that passes through a line and a point not on the line? For example, the line $y=7x-7$ and the point $x=3,y=0,z=8$. I've tagged this as homework, but it's simply curiosity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:choose two point in this line like$(1,0,0) (2,7,0)$then find Equation of a plane by tree point $$(1,0,0), (2,7,0),(3,0,8)$$

Comment: Of course. Thanks

Comment: @Peter4075:your welcome